# Init and init with parameters

Tags: objective-c, class, initialization

Here is the code :

```
@implementation Accumulateur

    // Constructor
    - (id) init
    {
        return ([self initWithTotal:0]);
    }

    - (id) initWithTotal:(int)aTotal
    {
        AccumulateurMoyen   *ac;

        if ((ac = [[AccumulateurMoyen alloc] init]) == nil)
        {
            [self release];
            return (nil);
        }
        return ([self initWithTotal:aTotal andAccumulateurMoyen:ac]);
    }

    - (id) initWithTotal:(int)aTotal 
    andAccumulateurMoyen:(AccumulateurMoyen *)aAcMoyen
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            [aAcMoyen retain];
            [acMoyen release];
            acMoyen = aAcMoyen;
            total = aTotal;
        }
        return (self);
    }
@end
```

The problem is here :  `if ((ac = [[AccumulateurMoyen alloc] init]) == nil)`
As I redefined `init`, the `init` called is mine and not that of `NSObject`...
I dont have idea, how i can do that correctly (`AccumulateurMoyen` is subclass of `Accumulateur`)

Thx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably undesired recursion there: `[[AccumulateurMoyen alloc] init]` tries to create new `AccumulateurMoyen` but that results in nested `initWithTotal:` which again tries to create another `AccumulateurMoyen` instance etc.

I.e. your code tries to create `Accumulateur` which has member `acMoyen` set to new instance of `AccumulateurMoyen`, which again has its `acMoyen` set to another new instance of `AccumulateurMoyen` etc.

You must to break the endless recursion. E.g. in `initWithTotal:`, replace the line

```
if ((ac = [[AccumulateurMoyen alloc] init]) == nil)
```

with

```
if ((ac = [[AccumulateurMoyen alloc] initWithTotal:0 andAccumulateurMoyen:nil]) == nil)
```

I.e. the nested `AccumulateurMoyen` will have its member set to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I think you have a structural problem here. Why your super class need to have an reference to a class that extend it? I think your best option to it is think again how your class structure will be.

But in your subClass you can change the init method to so your problem will disappear.

```
(id)init {
    return ([NSObject init]);
}
```

Comment: Because Accumuluteur has a instance variable type of AccumulateurMoyen :/

Comment: So all yours AccumulateurMoyen need to have an reference to an AccumulateurMoyen that will have a reference to other AccumulateurMoyen ? No, it can not be that way :P

Comment: hmm.. no :s You have an idea ? :p

Comment: Maybe you need a common super class to AccumulateurMoyen and to Accumulateur, that implements the methods you want they to share, and this way your Accumulateur can have only one AccumulateurMoyen, and eliminate the loop. To told you what is the best way only knowing more about your problem, this is only a suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I had a big structural problem, because i confused between composition and inheritance. "Why your super class need to have an reference to a class that extend it?". Thx you anyway :)